I'm trying to create an AppleScript that prints to an specific Print Plugin
I'm trying to print to PDF using a Print Plugin I have (called "PDF Redux").
I have an script in place but I'm not being able to open the PDF menu and selecting the correct plugin.
This is the code I have:
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Numbers"
            set frontmost to true
            
            keystroke "p" using {option down, command down}
            
            delay 2
            
            click menu item "PDF Redux" of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
        end tell
    end tell
    

It's stuck in not finding the PDF menu in the dialog box.
Any help would be great. Thanks.
UPDATE:
I was able to do it by borrowing some code from another question here:
perform action "AXShowMenu" of menu button 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            click menu item 8 of menu 1 of menu button 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1


This is the source.

Before you use a menu item, you must open the menu. I don't have this particular plugin so I'll use '…as pdf' instead. Modify accordingly. I included the corresponding method for the print sheet but your keystroke is also a valid approach.
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Numbers"
        set frontmost to true
        
        -- open print sheet
        set mf to menu "File" of menu bar 1
        perform action "AXPress" of mf
        delay 0.1
        perform action "AXPress" of menu item "Print Without Preview…" of mf
        delay 0.1
        
        -- pdf menu
        perform action "AXPress" of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        perform action "AXPress" of menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu "PDF" of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
        
    end tell
end tell


Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting the same result...
"Unable to get menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Numbers"."
